# Change the Table-Value Function to Inline from Multi-line

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-tuning

I'm trying to change a Table-Valued Function to improve the performance of a Stored Procedure but I can't get the same result. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Original:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_eess1] (
@institucion int ,
@disa int,
@red int,
@mred int) RETURNS @tbl TABLE (idlista [int] IDENTITY, institucion [int], disa [int], red [int], mred [int], establecimiento varchar(10)) AS BEGIN
IF (@institucion=1) -- First Condition */ where @institucion=1 then UNION ALL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl ([institucion], [disa], [red], [mred], [establecimiento])
    SELECT DISTINCT [c_institucion], [c_disa], [c_red], [c_microred], [codrenae] FROM [dbo].[RENAE]
    WHERE 

    [c_institucion]=@institucion AND [c_disa]=(CASE @disa WHEN -1 THEN [c_disa] ELSE @disa END)
    AND [c_red]=(CASE @red WHEN -1 THEN [c_red] ELSE @red END)
    AND [c_microred]=(CASE @mred WHEN -1 THEN [c_microred] ELSE @mred END)
END  ELSE
BEGIN
IF (@institucion=15) -- Second Condition */ where @institucion=15 then UNION ALL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl ([institucion], [disa], [red], [mred], [establecimiento])
    SELECT DISTINCT [c_institucion], [c_disa], [c_red], [c_microred], [codrenae] FROM [dbo].[RENAE]
    WHERE [c_institucion]='1' AND [c_disa]=(CASE @disa WHEN -1 THEN [c_disa] ELSE @disa END)
    AND [c_red]=(CASE @red WHEN -1 THEN [c_red] ELSE @red END)
    AND [c_microred]=(CASE @mred WHEN -1 THEN [c_microred] ELSE @mred END)

    INSERT INTO @tbl ([institucion], [disa], [red], [mred], [establecimiento])
    SELECT [org].[CodigoOrganizacion], [di].[iddisa], [r].[idred], [mi].[idmred], CAST ([es].[idestablecimiento] AS varchar) FROM [dbo].[Establecimientos] es
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[microred] mi ON [mi].[idmred]=[es].[microred]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Red] r ON [mi].[red] = [r].[idred]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Disa] di ON [r].[disa] = [di].[iddisa]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organizacion] org ON [di].[institucion] = [org].[CodigoOrganizacion]
    WHERE [org].[CodigoOrganizacion] in ('2','3','4','5','6','13') AND [di].[iddisa]=(case @disa when -1 then [iddisa] else @disa end) AND [r].[idred]=(case @red when -1 then [idred] else @red end)  AND [mi].[idmred]=(case @mred when -1 then [idmred] else @mred end)
END
ELSE
BEGIN  -- Third Condition? */ where @institucion is not (1,15) then UNION ALL
    INSERT INTO @tbl ([institucion], [disa], [red], [mred], [establecimiento])
    SELECT [org].[CodigoOrganizacion], [di].[iddisa], [r].[idred], [mi].[idmred], CAST ([es].[idestablecimiento] AS varchar) FROM [dbo].[Establecimientos] es
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[microred] mi ON [mi].[idmred]=[es].[microred]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Red] r ON [mi].[red] = [r].[idred]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Disa] di ON [r].[disa] = [di].[iddisa]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organizacion] org ON [di].[institucion] = [org].[CodigoOrganizacion]
    WHERE [org].[CodigoOrganizacion]=@institucion AND [di].[iddisa]=(case @disa when -1 then [iddisa] else @disa end) AND [r].[idred]=(case @red when -1 then [idred] else @red end)  AND [mi].[idmred]=(case @mred when -1 then [idmred] else @mred end) 
END END
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: You have to post code before and after changes and your results (expected and actual). It's unclear what's your issue and what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by creating one big query using `union all`, and moving the conditions from the `if` expressions to the where clauses of the inner queries. Also, instead of the `Identity` column in the return table, wrap the entire `union all` in another query and select `row_number over(order by @@spid)` (which returns an arbitrary raw number since it's ordered by a constant):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_eess1] 
(
    @institucion int ,
    @disa int,
    @red int,
    @mred int
)

RETURNS TABLE 

AS BEGIN

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As idlista, *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                [c_institucion] As [institucion], 
                [c_disa] As [disa], 
                [c_red] AS [red], 
                [c_microred] AS [mred], 
                [codrenae] AS [establecimiento]
        FROM [dbo].[RENAE]
        WHERE @institucion=1 -- First condition
        AND [c_institucion]=@institucion 
        AND [c_disa] = CASE @disa WHEN -1 THEN [c_disa] ELSE @disa END
        AND [c_red] = CASE @red WHEN -1 THEN [c_red] ELSE @red END
        AND [c_microred] = CASE @mred WHEN -1 THEN [c_microred] ELSE @mred END

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT [c_institucion], [c_disa], [c_red], [c_microred], [codrenae] 
        FROM [dbo].[RENAE]
        WHERE @institucion=15 -- Second condition
        AND [c_institucion]='1' 
        AND [c_disa] = CASE @disa WHEN -1 THEN [c_disa] ELSE @disa END
        AND [c_red] = CASE @red WHEN -1 THEN [c_red] ELSE @red END
        AND [c_microred] = CASE @mred WHEN -1 THEN [c_microred] ELSE @mred END

        UNION ALL

        SELECT [org].[CodigoOrganizacion], [di].[iddisa], [r].[idred], [mi].[idmred], CAST ([es].[idestablecimiento] AS varchar) 
        FROM [dbo].[Establecimientos] es
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[microred] mi ON [mi].[idmred]=[es].[microred]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Red] r ON [mi].[red] = [r].[idred]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Disa] di ON [r].[disa] = [di].[iddisa]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organizacion] org ON [di].[institucion] = [org].[CodigoOrganizacion]
        WHERE 
        (
            (
                @institucion=15 -- Second condition
                AND [org].[CodigoOrganizacion] in ('2','3','4','5','6','13')
            )
            OR 
            (
                @institucion NOT IN(1, 15) -- Third condition
                AND [org].[CodigoOrganizacion] = @institucion
            )
        )
        AND [di].[iddisa] = case @disa when -1 then [iddisa] else @disa end  
        AND [r].[idred] = case @red when -1 then [idred] else @red end 
        AND [mi].[idmred]= case @mred when -1 then [idmred] else @mred end

    )

END
```